# Invoking IronPython function from C# after IronPython runtime was disposed

Tags: c#, .net, clr, ironpython, dynamic-language-runtime

Suppose we have the following code in IronPython:

```
def hello():
    print "Hello from Python"
```

We call function `hello()` in the following C# code:

```
    private static void GetPythonFunction()
    {
        ScriptRuntime scriptRuntime = IronPython.Hosting.Python.CreateRuntime();
        ScriptScope scope = scriptRuntime.ExecuteFile(@"Python\helloFunc.py");
        Action hello = scope.GetVariable<Action>("hello");
        hello();
        scriptRuntime.Shutdown();
        hello(); // after IronPython runtime was disposed
    }
```

Which gives us result:

```
Hello from Python
Hello from Python
```

Why the second call `hello()` works twice even though the runtime environment was disposed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Shutdown` doesn't actually terminate the runtime, it just runs some cleanup routines. Things might be in a strange state afterwards, though, so there's no guarantee anything will work.

Plus, `hello` probably (I don't recall the exact details of how the delegates are created) has references to the runtime and engine keeping everything from being GC's.